# Must atomic fences be paired

Tags: c++, thread-synchronization

I have seen the talk *atomic<> weapons* and other talks about atomics, but one question never gets addressed.
Do I have to match a release with an acquire in all executions of a function?

Is this code valid?
The release only happens on some executions of foo.

```
atomic<int> atom;

int foo( int b ) {
    auto loaded_a = atom.load( memory_order_acquire );
    auto a = loaded_a;
    if( a < b ) {
        a++;
        a.compare_exchange_strong( loaded_a, a, memory_order_release, memory_order_relaxed ); 
    }
    return a;
}
```

In this function foo() only updates atom if the current thread was the one that got to increment it. Otherwise atom is not updated.

Comment: Yes whenever you acquire a lock, you should always release it. You can use a variable to check if you've released it inside the `a<b` condition. And if you haven't released it, then do so outside the condition.

Comment: @Nina `memory_order_acquire` does not acquire a lock, it only specifies how memory is accessed (reordering (or not) and visibility).

Comment: Then I'm not sure. But the general rule is to always call a release on your acquire.

Comment: *"Is this code valid?"* No - it's ill-formed. It attempts to call a method on an `int` variable.